# git pull not getting the latest commit

Tags: git, github

Hi I am trying to pull the changes of my latest commit in git. When I log into github, I can see my latest commit though when i run the following commands not seeing my local getting updated.I do not have multiple branches. Just one that is origin/master. Not sure why it is not pulling the latest changes that i checked in this morning

Following are the commands that I have tried

To check the history of the last two commits

```
git log -p - 2
```

Following commands to get the latest

```
    git fetch -all
    git pull origin master

    git fetch origin master
    git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Are you even using `git pull`?

Comment: 'Did you tried' git pull origin master

Comment: I tried that. I get a message Already uptodate

Comment: Just curious. Why are you using `reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: are you sure you have actually ***pushed*** that commit?  And are you sure you have pushed it to *origin master* ?

Comment: when i login to github i can see my commit

Comment: what gives `git remove -v` ?

Comment: Arount probably meant `git remote -v` : what is your list of remote repos ? is `origin` linked to your github repo ?

Comment: when i run git remove -v , I see the following origin github.com/ranjitmenon/mrdb.git (fetch) origin github.com/ranjitmenon/mrdb.git (push)

Comment: @Tom: ok. On your local repo, does `git log -2 origin/master` show the commits you expect at the tip of the master branch ?

Comment: Yes I can see my latest commit after running that command

Comment: So why is it not downloading then